# Entra ID (Azure AD) - Account Login Fail (Password Incorrect) After Joining Entra ID (Adding work account)

Tags: windows, azure, entra-id

I have a windows 11 desktop with a local administrator account and added a work account using the Entra ID link on the join prompt (following a MS docs article to the letter).

The join was successful, and after a restart I go to login using that users email address associated with the work acct that was just joined and get password error. The password is one-thousand-percent correct, else I couldn't join in the first place, and I've quadruple checked it, twice.

I log back into the local admin account and see the account listed in Settings -> Accounts -> Other Users (see pic)

Alternatively, I've read that Azure AD users cannot login to local machines without an on-prem DC to sync between the two, which is contrary to what i've read is possible in the documentation but much of it is outdated, renamed, with screenshots that do not match what is viewed in admin dashboards etc, so im thoroughly miffed.

I've tried logging in using the following conventions:

- azuread\username
- username@workdomain.com

Any ideas appreciated.

[Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifdqi.jpg)

[Settings > Users > Other: Work/School](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX0GF.jpg)

dsregcmd /status output:

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device State                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
         AzureAdJoined : YES
      EnterpriseJoined : NO
          DomainJoined : NO
       Virtual Desktop : NOT SET
           Device Name : dev04
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device Details                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
              DeviceId : ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-c89f185ZZZZZ
            Thumbprint : ZZZZZZZZ42BF67427D9A8DA4D78771ZZZZZZZZZZ
```

DeviceCertificateValidity : [ 2024-01-27 00:45:22.000 UTC -- 2034-01-27 01:15:22.000 UTC ]
KeyContainerId : ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-9554ZZZZZZZZ
KeyProvider : Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider
TpmProtected : YES
DeviceAuthStatus : SUCCESS

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Tenant Details                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
            TenantName : workdomain.com
              TenantId : ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-8d95-8edaZZZZZZZZ
           AuthCodeUrl : https://login.microsoftonline.com/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-8d95-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/oauth2/authorize
        AccessTokenUrl : https://login.microsoftonline.com/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-8d95-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/oauth2/token
                MdmUrl : 
             MdmTouUrl : 
      MdmComplianceUrl : 
           SettingsUrl : 
        JoinSrvVersion : 2.0
            JoinSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/EnrollmentServer/device/
             JoinSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
         KeySrvVersion : 1.0
             KeySrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/EnrollmentServer/key/
              KeySrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
    WebAuthNSrvVersion : 1.0
        WebAuthNSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/webauthn/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-8d95-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/
         WebAuthNSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
DeviceManagementSrvVer : 1.0
DeviceManagementSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/manage/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-8d95-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/
 DeviceManagementSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User State                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
                NgcSet : NO
       WorkplaceJoined : NO
         WamDefaultSet : NO
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SSO State                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
            AzureAdPrt : NO
   AzureAdPrtAuthority : 
 AcquirePrtDiagnostics : PRESENT
  Previous Prt Attempt : 2024-01-27 01:25:09.574 UTC
        Attempt Status : 0xc00484c0
         User Identity : mrspock@workdomain.com
       Credential Type : Password
        Correlation ID : ZZZZZZZZ-d335-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-9deb95ZZZZZZ
          Endpoint URI : https://sso.godaddy.com/v1/wss/trust/XX/XXXXXXXX
           HTTP Method : POST
            HTTP Error : 0x800484c0
           HTTP status : 405
     Server Error Code :
```

Server Error Description :
EnterprisePrt : NO
EnterprisePrtAuthority :

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Diagnostic Data                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
    AadRecoveryEnabled : NO
Executing Account Name : dev04\mrspock
           KeySignTest : PASSED

    DisplayNameUpdated : YES
      OsVersionUpdated : YES
       HostNameUpdated : NO

  Last HostName Update : NONE
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IE Proxy Config for Current User                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
  Auto Detect Settings : YES
Auto-Configuration URL : 
     Proxy Server List : 
     Proxy Bypass List :
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| WinHttp Default Proxy Config                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
           Access Type : DIRECT
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ngc Prerequisite Check                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
        IsDeviceJoined : YES
         IsUserAzureAD : NO
         PolicyEnabled : NO
      PostLogonEnabled : YES
        DeviceEligible : YES
    SessionIsNotRemote : YES
        CertEnrollment : none
          PreReqResult : WillNotProvision
```

For more information, please visit https://www.microsoft.com/aadjerrors

Comment: From a command prompt on the device run the command **dsregcmd /status** and post the device state in your question. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/devices/troubleshoot-device-dsregcmd

Comment: thx, forgot about that added

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more about your current environment, do you have a hybrid environment with identity synchronization? Have you checked the sign in logs and the audit logs if there was anything relevant there? Did you logon with the user principal name?

Comment: No hybrid environment in this network. It is mostly as described, an azure ad subscription with a few users and adding one (the global admin in this instance but ideally all users will be able to login to any machine using their azure ad login) to a bare metal device joined to azure ad via the add work user, restarting then attempting to login.

Comment: Are you using Okta? I am having the same exact issue. I am able to sign into a laptop with my username, but if I don't immediately setup Windows Hello, I will be locked out of the machine. The only way I can sign into machines normally is if I use my .onmicrosoft.com global admin account.